# React router on electron can't change history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, electron, react-router-v4

I've been trying to create a SPA on an electron project using React, React-Router and typescript (boostrapped from [here](https://github.com/Robinfr/electron-react-typescript)).

I'm currently just trying to make it reroute to a different route via a `<Link>` but I'm getting an error in the console saying

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://settings/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://localhost:2003' and URL 'http://localhost:2003/'.
```

where `localhost:2003` is the port associated with the project. I'm not sure how I can fix this as I believe this is a problem specific with electron? Not sure..

The code I'm running is exactly the same as https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-river-9yrbv

(please to go /app first in the sandbox)

Answer (score 1):

You mad mistake to load `props` in `App` function.

```
function App(props) {
  console.log(props);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* {props} // Remove this line... */}
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <ProtectedRoute path="/app" component={MainComponent} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You have to wrap `App` component via `Route`.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route } from "react-router-dom";

...
...

render(
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
  </Router>,
  rootElement
);
```

Now you can get the `props` in `console.log`.

Here is the updated working code for you.
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-elion-qr1qf

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Not sure if this is the solution to the links not working

Comment: You have to wrap your app component with `Route`. I have updated the code here https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-elion-qr1qf